# Multiple Mod_ReWrites on one site - Possible? (Wordpress blog in root directory, CodeIgniter project in subdirectory)

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter

Currently I am creating a project with CodeIgniter that is contained within a subdirectory of my domain. For this example we'll call it domain.com/test.

I also have Wordpress installed on this domain, and all of its files are in the root. For instance, if you navigate to my domain.com then it pulls up the Wordpress blog. I currently have the Wordpress mod_rewrite activated so that it uses friendly-URLs.

For those of you that aren't familiar with CodeIgniter, all requests are routed through index.php in the project's root folder. So, in this case, it'd be domain.com/text/index.php. A request to the application would be sent like domain.com/test/index.php/somecontroller/method.

What I'd like to do, is for any incoming request that is directed towards the /test/ folder, or some subdirectory therein I'd like it to appropriately rewrite the URL so the index.php isn't included. (As per the example above, it'd end up being domain.com/test/somecontroller/method)

For any OTHER request, meaning anything that's not within the /test/ directory, I would like it to route the request to Wordpress.

I would imagine it's a simple RewriteCond to make it check to see if the request is for the /test/ directory or a subdirectory therein, but I've no idea how to do it. Perhaps you can't have more than one set of Rewrite Rules per site.

I will include the recommended mod_rewrite rules for each application.

Wordpress: (Currently used)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

CodeIgniter: (Pulled from their [Wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/))

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Any and all help is much appreciated!!

Thanks,

-Sootah

Comment: Apparently all I really had to do was add the .htaccess to the /test/ subdirectory and the rules contained within it apparently override the parent directories rules.

However, I'd still like to know if this is doable in one .htaccess.

Comment: You need the separate .htaccess files because if a user is going into the test directory, the .htaccess in the root won't be seen thus its' instructions ignored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Myself and Stormdrain - As stated in my comment above (and expounded upon by Stormdrain), simply putting the CodeIgniter .htaccess in the /test/ subdirectory did the trick.

Ah, I should also note that I did have to modify the CodeIgniter .htaccess BasePath line from this:
    RewriteBase /

to this:
    RewriteBase /test/

Hopefully this helps anybody else that has the same/a similar question.

-[Sootah](http://www.tweaksforgeeks.com)